# Popup the value in the textblock by another textbox's text

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have one textbox in the view. If I input a value in textbox A, then textblock B's value will be displayed automatically. The relationship between the two properties is defined in a dictionary in my ViewModel.

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = LoadFromDb();
// dict["01"] = "USA";
// dict["02"] = "ENG";
// If I input 01 in code textbox, then the country textblockwill display USA.
```

The textbox and textblock are in the celltemplate. Let me give you the example.

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Name="radGridView1" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowGroupFooters="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
 <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Code" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Code}">
     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Code}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Country" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Country}">
     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
</telerik:RadGridView.GridViewDataColumns>
```

I can't bind them in my model class as model class has no the information of the dictionary.

So what is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can achieve this using code behind?

Comment: I thought about it, the textbox is in the gridview's column's celltemplate. Can we still do it?

Comment: Can you please provide the XAML? Thank you!

Comment: where is textbox B? and also is `Code.Code` the right path?

Comment: One is textbox, the other one is textblock. Sorry for the typo, I corrected it.

Comment: You can implement it with value converter

Comment: @Rekshino, I have two status. One is readonly status. ALL data come from DB. The second status is to add new row, a new row will be added to the grid. If I input the code, then I can get the country. I don't want interrupt the first status if using converter.

Comment: it still looks a little off. not both `DataMemberBinding` and `Text` should be the same. one should be `{Binding}`

Comment: Which "status" do you mean? Sorry, but I can't follow you. What is your DataContext? Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rekshino, status means mode. I have read mode, in this case, popup the data from the database. Another mode is insert mode. I add a new row and will save the row to database. DataContext is in the ViewModel, it is a collection.

Comment: @Bijan, if I use `{Binding}` without the name of the property, how can I save the row to the DB?

Comment: Using the binding in its cell template. It&amp;#39;s not redundant but wrong to set the path in both bindings

Comment: @Bijan, even remove that. It is still not solving my problem.

Comment: Why isn't the dictionary with the mappings defined in the "model" class? Add it or create another class that contains the properties along with the dictionary and bind to this one.

Comment: @mm8, I have to new up the model in many cases. Not sure if it is a good idea if add the dictionary in model.

Comment: Create a *view* model. This is where the dictionary *and* the source properties belong. Where else should you define the mapping that is obviously part of your UI application logic?

Answer (score 2):

Do bind Country column to the whole data entry and use converter to display readonly value: in case it comes from DB - unmodified, otherwise - get it from dictionary.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ValueConverter x:Key="convResName"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Country" DataMemberBinding="{Binding}">
     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convResName}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource {x:Static local:YourViewModel.yourDictAsStaticProperty}}}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var person = value as Person;
        if (person==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var dict = parameter as Dictionary<string, string>;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.Country))
        {
            try
            {
                person.Country = dict[person.Code];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException exc)
            {
                //handle exc
            }
        }
        return person.Country;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `convResName`?

Comment: Key for your Converter, defined in resource. I have updated code.

Comment: Almost done, how to put the dictionary in the resource? It is a property in ViewModel.

Comment: If you have your Dictionary as property in ViewModel, then make it static and see changed code.

Comment: Actually, if you make dictionary static, then you don't need to transfer it as ConverterParameter, just access it in code from converter.

Comment: It is not working when I input the text in the box, after I move the mouse to somewhere. It lost focus; and the converter code can't be reached. Perhaps I have to think code behind event.

Comment: Try set the binding's trigger for input `TextBox` to ´UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Does your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged??